# Hide folder on Plone 4.0.5

Tags: hide, directory, plone

I'm using "Explore" in the left menu to show the content of a "Doc" folder. This folder originates from the top menu.

Is it possible to hide the "Doc" folder from the top menu?

I was thinking of moving it to admin, but I do not like that solution.

Thanks. Nikolaj G.

Comment: Is this a Plone question? Not familiar with the terminology, unless maybe you are referring to Enfold Desktop. In any event, please add more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a plone question, then you can hide any folder from the top menu by editing the folder, and setting "Exclude from navigation" in the metadata (Settings tab).

Comment: @marcosfromero Thanks for the edit - I couldn't remember which tab and it's taken me until now to get back to the net to correct it.

Comment: Thanks aclark, marcosfromero and Auspex for using your time on my sometimes trivial questions. Done. Have a nice day. Nikolaj G.